# cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no file named sys thrown from distutils setup script

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, cx-freeze

When I execute the following distutils setup script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'excludes': ['pyro', 'tkinter', 'sqlalchemy']
    }
}

executables = [Executable('script.py')] 

setup(name='exe_script', executables=executables, options=options)
```

I received the following exception:

> ...
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py",
> line 762,
> in Create module.file, module.name)
>
> cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no file named sys (for module urllib.sys)

I found 2([1](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/121/cx_freezefreezerconfigerror-no-file-named), [2](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/127/collectionssys-error)) similar issues in the cx_freeze's bitbucket repository however none of them solved my problem.

Thanks in advance